# Is it possible Saving multiple key:value in a single cookie in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies

Is it possible to save multiple key:value pair in a single cookie ?

i.e something like option['name'], option['age'], ....

It may be possible by using a single like with some join operands **[1]** and then exploding to get all the values but do I need to re-invent the wheel or is it possible ?

**[1]**
name=Hitman,age=47 and then exploding with ,

Comment: _Is it possible to save multiple key:value pair in a single cookie ?_ Ya you can because cookie's value could be anything.

Comment: Sure. No need to reinvent the wheel, you could store it using any reversible serialization format. Look into `json_encode()`, `http_build_query()` or `serialize()` just to name a few options. Do keep in mind that there is a limit to how many bytes you can store in a cookie. If it grows too large (or if you have too many of them), your webserver will start returning 400 responses with a “Request header or cookie too large” description.

Comment: @rickdenhaan can you please share some code ?

Comment: @nice_dev How to ? please share some code.

Answer (score 1):

Of the various serialization options PHP has to offer, I would choose `http_build_query()`. A simple example would be as follows:

```
$data = [
  'name' => 'Hitman',
  'age' => 47
];

setcookie("mycookie", http_build_query($data));
```

The "mycookie" cookie will now have the value `name=Hitman&age=47`.

To read this value back, you can use `parse_str()`:

```
$data = [];
parse_str($_COOKIE['mycookie'], $data);
```

The reason for choosing `http_build_query()` over options such as `json_encode()` or `serialize()` is that those two use commas as separators. In the HTTP headers for cookies, commas are also used to separate individual cookies. This might cause issues. `http_build_query()` will URL-encode any special characters, this includes commas as `%2C`. This is a little safer to use as cookie values.

You could still use JSON or serialize, but I would recommend passing the resulting value through `base64_encode()` as well to ensure the value is safe for use in the Cookie and Set-Cookie headers. This does increase the number of bytes required for the value, so you'll run into the "Request header or cookie too large" error sooner.